# IE10 does not support css transitions for padding?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

How can I css transition the `padding` of an element in IE10? Is it not supported or am I missing something?

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/755f7s1k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not supported in IE10 i think, but works perfectly on IE11 and edge

Comment: Indeed, it seems you're right. Instead of transitioned `transform`, which is supported.